# bash tee script output to file and stdout does not update timestamp

Tags: bash

I have the following bash command to tee script output to stdout and logfile. It works and I can see the live output. However the date is not changing. Is there any way to instruct exec to evaluate date in a dynamic way.

```
#!/bin/bash

LOGFILE="/tmp/te/script.log"
exec 1> >( stdbuf -e 0 -o 0 sed "s/^/$(date '+[%F %T]'): /" | tee -a ${LOGFILE}) 2>&1

echo "Started"
sleep 2
echo "Done sleeping"
sleep 2
echo "Another sleep"
sleep 2

echo "Done"
```

Thanks

Comment: Completely to be expected. `sed` is started *once*, and `date` is run *once* -- you wouldn't want it to be any other way; invoking external tools is extremely slow, so the log process couldn't necessarily keep up if you had a fast run of content going through.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to use `ts` to add timestamps instead. For Ubuntu, `apt install moreutils`

```
exec 1> >(stdbuf -e0 -o0 ts '[%F %T]' | tee -a "$LOGFILE") 2>&1
# ...................... ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have bash 4.1 or newer, it has a very efficient means of calculating timestamp via `printf %()T`. Thus:

```
logfile="/tmp/te/script.log"
exec > >(while IFS= read -r line; do
          printf '%([%F %T])T %s\n' -1 "$line"
         done >>"$logfile") 2>&1
```

This uses a [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) `while read` loop to iterate over lines, and uses `printf` to generate a line of output with the current timestamp for each.

<sub>(If you get the error `` printf: `(': invalid format character ``, that means your bash is too old; you could instead `printf '%s %s\n' "$(date '+[%F %T]')" "$line"`, but this is going to be much slower).</sub>